# Url rewriting not working as expected

Tags: wcf, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I am trying to rewrite the rule so that if no `.svc` comes in URL it should rewrite and append `.svc` in URL.

These are my rules:

```
<rewrite>   
  <rules>
    <rule name="RemoveSVC" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="localhost/RestApp/Services/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/(.*)$" />    
      <action type="Rewrite" url="localhost/RestApp/Services/{R:1}.svc/{R:2}" 
              appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>    
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Can anybody tell me why is this rule not working?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
<rewrite>   
  <rules>
    <rule name="RemoveSVC" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="localhost/RestApp/Services/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/(.*)" />    
      <action type="Rewrite" url="localhost/RestApp/Services/{R:1}.svc/{R:2}" 
              appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>    
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Remove the `$` sign on the end.

I'd also get rid of the `localhost/` part because that would only work on your local dev PC, when you deploy into production it won't be `localhost` any more:

```
<match url="RestApp/Services/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="RestApp/Services/{R:1}.svc/{R:2}" 
        appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
```